# delay between closing angularjs modal and redirect

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im using an angularjs modal but when i need to redirect to another view, i need to close it and put a delay to hide the shadow from the new page.
Is that any other faster solution?

Im using angularUI modal.

```
   var element = angular.element('#mymodal');
        element.modal('hide');


    setTimeout(function(){
        document.location.href='#newPage/'+process.pk;
    }, 350);**
```

Comment: Use Angular UI modal, not jQuery.

Comment: but im using angular UI modal.                                      var element = angular.element('#mymodal');
element.modal('show');

Comment: No, that's not Angular UI, that's jqlite / jQuery. If your site has the jQuery library, which it appear so, jqLite gets augmented with the full jQuery library. You're creating a jQuery object when you call angular.element(). See this example: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Comment: Please create a plunkr so ee can help efficiently

Comment: thanks, i used angular UI and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the first install angular UI Bootstrap , inject your module 
here is a [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for UI modal , the modal returning you promise and you can also resolve data from modal. In that case by using promise you don't need to use timeout, and also in angular try to use `$location` provider instead of `document.location`